# Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FF6692B7628 в *.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00000000FDFDFDFD

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<random>
using namespace std;
class matrix{
public:
    double** x;
    int row;
    int line;
    void CrateMatrix(int l, int r) {
        row = r;
        line = l;
        x = new double* [line];
        for (int i = 0; i < line; i++) {
            x[i] = new double[row];
            //for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            //  x[i][j] =1 /*m[j]*/;
            //}
        }
    }
    void fillmatrix() {
        for (int i = 0; i < line; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
                x[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            }

        }
    }
    matrix operator * (matrix& v) {
        if (this->row != v.line) {
            std::cout << "errr lime and row" << std::endl;
        }
        matrix c;
        int m = v.row;
        int n =v.line;
        int p = this->line;
        c.CrateMatrix(m, p);
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < p; j++) {
                double sum = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    sum +=this->x[i][k];
                }
                cout << " sum =:" << " " << sum << endl;
                c.x[i][j]= sum;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    void out() {
        for (int i = 0; i < line; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
                cout << x[i][j] << " " << '\t';
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};
int main(){
    srand(0);
    matrix a;
    a.CrateMatrix(2, 3);
    a.fillmatrix();
    a.out();
    matrix b;
    matrix d;
    
    b.CrateMatrix(3, 4);
    b.fillmatrix();
    b.out();
    d = a * b;
    d.out();
    std::cout << " end ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А на какой строчке то она вызвана?

Comment: Так, просто - зачем `CrateMatrix`, если есть конструктор? И еще - ни копирования, ни присвоения - сплошные утечки памяти :) Кстати, и при умножении вы на самом деле ничего не умножаете.

Comment: я коеструктор потом хотел сделать , я знаю что не умножаю про случайно стер это  sum +=this x[i][k] * v.x[k][j]; вот это там должно было быть

Comment: на строчке  с                 for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    sum +=this->x[i][k];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перепишите один фрагмент вот так:

```
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    assert(i < this->row && k < this->line);
    sum +=this->x[i][k];
}
```

и убедитесь, что вы вылетаете за пределы вашей матрицы.

Что делать? Переписать аккуратно... По-моему, вы запутались, что у вас столбец, а что строка - и немудрено: назвали-то вы их одинаково: `line` и `row`... При создании ("Crate" :)) `line` у вас число строк, `row` - число столбцов.

Например, при умножении матриц должна получиться матрица с числом строк, как в первой, и столбцов, как во второй - а у вас

```
    int m = v.row;
    int p = this->line;
    c.CrateMatrix(m, p);
```

вроде как наоборот...

Comment: спасибо большое .

Answer (score 1):

Вообще вот переделанная ваша функция:

```
matrix operator * (matrix& v) {
    if (this->row != v.line) {
        std::cout << "errr lime and row" << std::endl;
    }
    matrix c;
    int m = v.row;
    int n = v.line;
    int p = this->line;
    c.CrateMatrix(p, v.row);
    for (int i = 0; i < line; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v.row; j++) {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < row; k++) {
                sum += this->x[i][k] * v.x[k][j];
            }
            cout << " sum =:" << " " << sum << endl;
            c.x[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Уже со строчкой: `sum += this->x[i][k] * v.x[k][j];`

Если конечно я вас правильно понял, то `line` у вас строка, а `row` это столбцы. Лучше переименовать их как `line` = `row`, а вот `row` = `col`